# It does not insert the data assigned from the MYSQL trigger

Tags: mysql

I am using a trigger to create and insert an email if the email field is null or empty, but don't insert anything

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_i_correo BEFORE INSERT ON examen_final
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF new.correo  = null OR new.correo = '' THEN
    SET new.correo = CORREO_ESTUDIANTE(new.nombre_estudiante, new.primer_apellido, new.segundo_apellido, '@mail.com');
END IF; 

END //
```

the function that returns the generated mail.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION CORREO_ESTUDIANTE(nombre_estudiante varchar(255), primer_apellido  varchar(255), segundo_apellido varchar(255), dominio varchar(255)) 
    RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE correo varchar(255);
        SET correo = concat(LEFT(nombre_estudiante, 1), primer_apellido, segundo_apellido, '@', dominio);
        RETURN correo;
    END; //
```

Comment: Ok it's true, but even though I put IS NULL, it still doesn't insert anything

Answer (score 1):

Change `new.correo = null` to `new.correo IS NULL` in your if statement. You cant check null with `=`.

Take look at [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html) link to mysql documentation.

Comment: Ok it's true, but even though I put IS NULL, it still doesn't insert anything.

Comment: Can you give us a sample query?

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your table/trigger/function in my environment and it worked using this `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO examen_final 
(nombre_estudiante, primer_apellido, segundo_apellido)
VALUES
('Carlos', 'Matías', 'Mena')
```

correo inserted with the value of **CMatíasMena@@mail.com** (I'd advise removing the `@` in the function or your trigger to avoid an invalid email address).

But back to your question, since it worked for me *(note: running an older version, 5.6)*, I would advise checking the user you're using to run the `INSERT` statement has `EVENT` and `TRIGGER` Privileges. Also, check if the user you used to create the Trigger and Function has the same Privileges

View a list of Privileges here:

```
SHOW PRIVILEGES;
```

View Grants for the user you're using:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();
```

View Grants for another user:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
```